# Открыть файл в js, найти строку и дополнить ее. Записать файл

Tags: javascript, html, парсер

в теле пишу функцию.

```js
  onload = function () {
    // вешаем обработчик события, срабатывающий при изменении input'а
    document.querySelector('fileInput').addEventListener('change', onFilesSelect, false);
  }
```

имя inputa записал какое имя записано в id в html.

в коде присутствует функция которая должна запускаться при выборе файла.
вот она.

```js
function onFilesSelect(e) {
  // получаем объект FileList
  var files = e.target.files,
    // div, куда помещается таблица с информацией о файлах
    output = document.getElementById('output'),
    // таблица с информацией
    table = document.createElement('table'),
    // её тело
    tbody = document.createElement('tbody'),
    // строка с информацией о файле (Перезаписывается каждый шаг цикла)
    row,
    // FileReader (Создаётся для каждого файла)
    fr,
    // объект file из FileList'a
    file,
    // массив с информацией о файле
    data;
 
  // Чистим контейнер с таблицей
  output.innerHTML = '';
 
  // Вставляем в таблицу её тело
  table.appendChild(tbody);
  // Определяем заголовок таблицы (Названия колонок)
  tbody.innerHTML = 
  "<tr><td>Имя</td><td>MIME тип</td><td>Размер (байт)</td><td>Превью</td></tr>";
 
  // Перебираем все файлы в FileList'е
  for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {    
    file = files[i];
    // Если в файле содержится изображение
    if(/text.*/.test(file.type)) {
      // узнаём информацию о нём
      data = [file.name, file.type, file.size];
      fr = new FileReader();
      // считываем его в строку base64
      fr.readAsDataURL(file);
      // как только файл загружен
      fr.onload = (function (file, data) {
alert("Loaded");
      }) (file, data);
    // Если файл не изображение
    } else {
      // то вместо превью выводим соответствующую надпись
      data = [file.name, file.type, file.size, 'Файл не является изображением'];
      appendFileInfo(tbody, data);
    }      
  }
  // помещаем таблицу с информацией о файле в div
  output.appendChild(table);  
}
```

Это из примера с загрузкой изображения.Пытался переделать на текст. Тишина.
Что не так, и может можно сделать проще? В итоге мне нужно получить строку, найти нужную последовательность символов, вставить текст и сохранить файл. Все это происходит при работе с браузером, но только локально, скорее всего только на Хром'е это нужно будет совершить.

в js файле моего расширения используется код jquery.
мне кажется этот код

```js
function onFilesSelect(e) {
 alert("Loaded");
 }
```

не может выполнится в нутри его(jquery) функций. Как правильно его разместить вне функций jquery?

сам инпут в html

```html
  <br>
  </br>
<input id="fileInput" type="file" size="50" onchange="onFilesSelect(event)">
<div id="fileOutput"></div>
 <br>
  </br>
```

Comment: что за расширение имеется ввиду? Причем тут jquery? В ответе уже есть решение как прочитать текст файла, и как вызвать  `click`.

Comment: Браузерное расширение имеется в виду. С jquery я получаю информацию с сайтов, которую я хочу записать в файл. Я просто хочу идти поступательно, для начала просто вывести алерт по загрузке файла через инпут.

Comment: Я запутался. Такое ощущение, что ты задал один вопрос, а в комментариях задал еще 2-3 вопроса никак не связанных с первым

Comment: Может тогда лучше задать новый вопрос в новой теме? Просто ответ на основной получен!

Comment: Да, лучше задать новый вопрос, и поподробнее описать что именно и как ты делаешь. Не забудь указать, что речь идет про расширение, это важно

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться методом [*.readAsText(...)*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText). В результате в функции *onload* можно будет получить текст загруженного файла.

С сохранением все печальнее. Раньше была речь про *FileSaver interface* и метод *saveAs* объекта window, но, похоже, что-то не задалось, и теперь про него нет упоминаний.

Но, можно создать элемент *A*, установить свойству href - objectURL для созданного Blob, в котором хранится измененный текст, добавить ему значение в свойство *download* и программно вызвать *click*.

В этом случае, сохранится файл с именем указанным в свойстве download. В зависимости от настроек браузера может показаться окошко с выбором места для сохранения, либо сохранится в папку для загрузок.

Пример:

```js
function saveFile(file, blob) {
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.download = file.name;
  a.href = url;
  a.click();

  // очищаем object URL
  setTimeout(function() {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }, 2000);
}

function onFilesSelect(e) {
  // получаем объект FileList
  var files = e.target.files;

  // Перебираем все файлы в FileList'е
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    let file = files[i];
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(e) {
      // сохраняем текст файла в переменную
      var textContent = e.target.result;

      // выводим на странице
      document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = textContent;

      // меняем что-то в строке
      var replaced = textContent.replace(/\w/g, '1$&1');

      // формируем blob
      var blob = new Blob([replaced]);

      // пытаемся сохранить
      if (!window.saveAs) {
        saveFile(file, blob);
      } else {
        window.saveAs(blob, file.name);
      }

    }

    // читаем файл как текст
    fileReader.readAsText(file);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="onFilesSelect(event)" />
<pre id="data"></pre>
```

Comment: Да, именно так я сейчас и сохраняю. Только как програмно нажать кнопку сохранения? Код выглядит так______________  var csv = '\n\n\n\n1; foo\n2; bar\n3; русский';______
var name = 'sheet';_____
document.write(____
  '<a href="data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,',______
  encodeURIComponent('\ufeff' + csv), //utf8 bom(чтоб эксель понял ____кодировку) + строка _____
  '" download="' + name + '.htm">' + name + '</a>');__________

Comment: @Михаил, комментарии не предназначены для кода, можешь отредактировать свой вопрос _добавив_ в него новую информацию

Comment: Хорошо! учту...

Comment: @Михаил, обновил ответ. Проблема была в слишком быстром вызове revokeObjectURL, из-за этого EDGE и FF пропускали скачивание.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, не могу просто по загрузке файла начать действовать...