# Как прочитать то, что я достал из файла, загруженного локально

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, парсер

Не пойму как мне обработать тескт который я получил в переменную contents?

```js
var filesExt = ['htm']; // массив расширений
var docx = document.getElementById("fileInput");
docx.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
var parts = $(this).val().split('.'); 
if(filesExt.join().search(parts[parts.length - 1]) != -1){
    alert('Good!');

 var file = docx.files[0];
 var textType = /text.*/;

 if (file.type.match(textType)) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
   var contents = event.target.result;
   console.log(contents);
  }
  reader.readAsText(file);
  
 } else {
  alert("File not supported!");
 }
} else {
    alert('WTF?!');
}
});
```

что только я не делал, и обычными методами, и jquery, и с какими только переменными не пытался. Все время undefined,null,init,object, но текст так и не достал...
contents выводится в алерт и консоль так как нужно, готовая страница, но вот как ее отредактировать?

вот что я вижу и в алерт и в консоль лог. Но больше никуда не могу вывести.

```html
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
<meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Excel 14">
<link id=Main-File rel=Main-File href="../&#1053;&#1086;&#1074;&#1099;&#1081;%20&#1090;&#1077;&#1082;&#1089;&#1090;&#1086;&#1074;&#1099;&#1081;%20&#1076;&#1086;&#1082;&#1091;&#1084;&#1077;&#1085;&#1090;.xls">
<link rel=File-List href=filelist.xml>
<link rel=Stylesheet href=stylesheet.css>
<style>
<!--table
 {mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\,";
 mso-displayed-thousand-separator:" ";}
@page
 {margin:1.0in .75in 1.0in .75in;
 mso-header-margin:.5in;
 mso-footer-margin:.5in;}
-->
</style>
<![if !supportTabStrip]><script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function fnUpdateTabs()
 {
  if (parent.window.g_iIEVer>=4) {
   if (parent.document.readyState=="complete"
    && parent.frames['frTabs'].document.readyState=="complete")
   parent.fnSetActiveSheet(0);
  else
   window.setTimeout("fnUpdateTabs();",150);
 }
}

if (window.name!="frSheet")
 window.location.replace("../&#1053;&#1086;&#1074;&#1099;&#1081;%20&#1090;&#1077;&#1082;&#1089;&#1090;&#1086;&#1074;&#1099;&#1081;%20&#1076;&#1086;&#1082;&#1091;&#1084;&#1077;&#1085;&#1090;.xls");
else
 fnUpdateTabs();
//-->
</script>
<![endif]>
</head>

<body link=blue vlink=purple>

<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=784 style='border-collapse:
 collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:588pt'>
 <col width=200 span=2 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:7314;
 width:150pt'>
 <col width=40 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:1462;width:30pt'>
 <col width=120 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:4388;width:90pt'>
 <col width=40 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:1462;width:30pt'>
 <col width=120 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:4388;width:90pt'>
 <col width=64 style='width:48pt'>
 <tr height=21 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl65 width=200 style='height:15.0pt;width:150pt'></td>
  <td width=200 style='width:150pt'></td>
  <td width=40 style='width:30pt'></td>
  <td width=120 style='width:90pt'></td>
  <td width=40 style='width:30pt'></td>
  <td width=120 style='width:90pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=60 style='mso-height-source:userset;height:45.0pt'>
  <td colspan=6 height=60 class=xl73 width=720 style='border-right:.5pt solid black;
  height:45.0pt;width:540pt'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl65 width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=21 style='height:15.75pt'>
  <td height=21 class=xl65 width=200 style='height:15.75pt;width:150pt'></td>
  <td class=xl65 width=200 style='width:150pt'></td>
  <td colspan=5 style='mso-ignore:colspan'></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=80 style='mso-height-source:userset;height:60.0pt'>
  <td height=80 class=xl66 width=200 style='height:60.0pt;width:150pt'>&#1053;&#1072;&#1080;&#1084;&#1077;&#1085;&#1086;&#1074;&#1072;&#1085;&#1080;&#1077;
  &#1086;&#1073;&#1086;&#1088;&#1091;&#1076;&#1086;&#1074;&#1072;&#1085;&#1080;&#1103;</td>
  <td class=xl67 width=200 style='width:150pt'>&#1058;&#1080;&#1087;</td>
  <td class=xl67 width=40 style='width:30pt'>&#1045;&#1076;.
  &#1048;&#1079;&#1084;.</td>
  <td class=xl68>&#1062;&#1077;&#1085;&#1072;</td>
  <td class=xl68>&#1050;-&#1074;&#1086;</td>
  <td class=xl69>&#1057;&#1091;&#1084;&#1084;&#1072;</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl72 width=200 style='height:15.0pt;width:150pt'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl71 width=200 style='width:150pt'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl72 width=40 style='width:30pt'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl72>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl72>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl72>&nbsp;</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
  </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl72 width=200 style='height:15.0pt;width:150pt'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl71 width=200 style='width:150pt'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl72 width=40 style='width:30pt'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl72>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl72>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl72>&nbsp;</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <![if supportMisalignedColumns]>
 <tr height=0 style='display:none'>
  <td width=200 style='width:150pt'></td>
  <td width=200 style='width:150pt'></td>
  <td width=40 style='width:30pt'></td>
  <td width=120 style='width:90pt'></td>
  <td width=40 style='width:30pt'></td>
  <td width=120 style='width:90pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
 </tr>
 <![endif]>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

мне нужно вот в этой строчке после текста вставить свой текст.

```html
<td height=20 class=xl72 width=200 style='height:15.0pt;width:150pt'>&nbsp;
```

Это будет заполненная ячейка таблицы.

ПРОДОЛЖЕНИЕ!

```js
var contents='';
var Loaded='';
var filesExt = ['htm']; // массив расширений
var docx = document.getElementById("fileInput");
 docx.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var parts = $(this).val().split('.'); 
    if(filesExt.join().search(parts[parts.length - 1]) != -1){
        alert('Good!');

  var file = docx.files[0];
  var textType = /text.*/;
  var loaded='';
  if (file.type.match(textType)) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   
   reader.onload = function(e) {
   window.contents = event.target.result;
    //if (contents!=''){loaded=1;}
    console.log(window.contents);
    window.Loaded=1;
    console.log(window.Loaded+'_1');
   }
   reader.readAsText(file);
   if(window.Loaded!='undefined') {console.log(window.contents);}
   console.log(window.Loaded+'_2');
   
  } else {
   alert("File not supported!");
  }
    } else {
        alert('WTF?!');
    }
 });
});
```

я работаю с контентс до того, как в него загрузятся данные и
здесь Loaded тоже все равно вызывается, не смотря на то что она не определена. Либо я не могу вытащить переменную контентс из функции.
Вопрос как обработать контентс после того, как в нее загрузится инфа?

Comment: console.log(contents); выдает всю страницу которую я загрузил, но как мне что то в ней изменить и так же записать в переменную?

Comment: Напишите что вам нужно заменить на что

Comment: _что только я не делал, и обычными методами, и jquery, и с какими только переменными не пытался._ - так напиши **что** делал и **как**. От этого может зависеть каким вопросом закрыть как дубликат: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/186999) или [Открыть файл в js, найти строку и дополнить ее. Записать файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/667555/186999)

Comment: там я так понимаю не знаю как прослушать инпут, я инпут слушаю, и получаю инфу, но не могу с ней работать. Вопрос обновил.

Comment: Что мне делать? Я ответа так и не получил. А новые вопросы будут отмечены как дубликаты и не будут решенными?